# curl_easy_init код ошибки / описание

Tags: c++, c, curl

Возможно ли узнать код ошибки и описание, если `curl_easy_init` завершился неудачно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя вот по этой цитате - нет, никаких подробностей узнать нельзя:

> It's a little design flaw really, but when I made the API that way
>   (back in 2000) I didn't really expect other errors than malloc()
>   failures to cause a NULL return.

[When curl_easy_init fails...](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2009-11/0243.html)

Comment: я видел это письмо, но 2009-й год, может что-то изменилось...

Comment: Нет, не изменилось, я добавлю сюда ответ с англ со https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50987505/how-to-get-error-reason-when-curl-easy-init-fails/50988014#50988014

Comment: @goldstar_labs Не изменилось. Если посмотрите на [сорцы этой функции](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/bc5a0b3e9f16a431523ae54822adc38c3a396a26/lib/easy.c#L354), то увидите, что коды возврата, кроме как завершения функции и вывода дебажных принтов, больше никак не используются. И извне никак не узнать, какой же там на самом деле был код ошибки. Вероятность ошибки можно снизить, предварительно и единожды  вызвав `curl_global_init`.

Comment: или собрать curl в debug режиме, а curl_global_init нужен всегда! это оксиома для данной библиотеки, ну и в конце конечно curl_global_cleanup